# Extract and write gitlab pipeline ID in gatling log

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gatling, gitlab-api, scala-gatling

I am new to both GITLAB and GATLING. I am trying to implement shift-left performance testing as part of CI/CD pipeline using the mentioned tool. Although I am very proficient with Jenkins and Jmeter. I am trying to write Gitlab Pipeline ID to gatling simulation log file.

I have referred to the GITLAB variable and $CI_PIPELINE_IID is used to expose the pipeline execution ID. In case of scala I can fetch or infuse environment variables using JAVA_OPTS but not able to fetch the gitlab pipeline id.

I did some further research and i was able to print the pipeline ID on the Gitlab Console

```
$ echo $CI_PIPELINE_ID
141683
```

Further I read as part of scala[Gitlab], CI variables can be used as ENV variables during the build, so retrieving them as 
System.getEnv("$CI_PIPELINE_IID")

But while i try the same I get null value.

```
val varPipelineId = System.getenv("$CI_PIPELINE_ID")
println(varPipelineId)
```

Console log:

```
$ echo $CI_PIPELINE_ID
141694
$ mkdir /opt/gatling/user-files/simulations/cloudnative/
$ cp gatling-reports/cloudnativems.scala /opt/gatling/user-files/simulations/cloudnative/
$ /opt/gatling/bin/gatling.sh -s cloudnative.cloudnativems
GATLING_HOME is set to /opt/gatling
null
```

Second Part of the requirement:
I want to write the value of pipeline id in gatling simulation.log file with each log entry

Actual format of simulation.log

```
REQUEST 1       account_movement_post   1553663401413   1553663404218   KO  status.find.in(200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,303), found 500
```

Modified format of simulation.log

```
REQUEST 1       account_movement_post   1553663401413   1553663404218   KO  status.find.in(200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,303), found 500 [pipeline_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a logical change - removed $ from the environment variable

```
val varPipelineId = System.getenv("CI_PIPELINE_ID")
println(varPipelineId)
```

Output:

```
  $ echo $CI_PIPELINE_ID
    141714
    $ mkdir /opt/gatling/user-files/simulations/cloudnative/
    $ cp gatling-reports/cloudnativems.scala /opt/gatling/user-files/simulations/cloudnative/
    $ /opt/gatling/bin/gatling.sh -s cloudnative.cloudnativems
    GATLING_HOME is set to /opt/gatling
    Some(141714)
```